# Capacitor Code 189S Identification

Tags: capacitor

I can't identify the small (3 or 4 mm diam) leaking cylindrical capacitor with radial leads on the circuit board in the picture. The code stamped on it is 189S. I'm just guessing it is 1.8 micro-farad electrolytic but I can't guess what "S" might mean. Is 1.8 micro-farad electrolytic correct? Please help.

[image: Capacitor - Humidity Sensor Control Board]

Comment: Looks like a quartz xtal, are you sure it's a cap?

Comment: P. Niezabitowski - Although the answer is probably now known, can you please edit the question and add another photo taken perpendicular to (i.e. straight down onto) the PCB in that area? It will help to see more of the surrounding components, their component designators, and related PCB tracks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a quartz crystal to me. I think it is X1 and was glued to the board...it's not leaking.

Comment: 1.89MHz? 189kHz perhaps?

Comment: Thank you peufeu, Elliot Alderson and rdtsc. I believe you're correct and I'm wrong re component id. Do you know why gluing is necessary? The circuit is 20 yrs old and part of a thermometer/hygrometer. Thanks again.